# How can I scrape multiple followers with Tweepy?

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

The Twitter API limit lets me only scrape 15-20 pages with 200 followers. After a 15 min break limit is set.

If I run my code new I don't want to start again at the beginning of a follower list, how can I step into where I left before the limitation?

My code looks like this with a Twitter user example who has 4.8 Mill follower.

```
def fetch_followers_to_df():
try:
    screen_name = "JeffBezos"
    
    # fetching the user
    user = api.get_user(screen_name=screen_name)
    num_followers = user.followers_count
    print(user.id)
    print(user.followers_count)
    
    cnt_followers = input()
    if cnt_followers == "":
        cnt_pages = float(num_followers) // 200
    print(cnt_pages)
    
    df_followers = pd.DataFrame(columns=["User", "ID", "Bio", "Location"])

    for page in tweepy.Cursor(
        api.get_followers, screen_name=screen_name, count=200
    ).pages(cnt_pages):
        for user in page:

            temp_dict = {
                "User": user.screen_name,
                "ID": user.id,
                "Bio": user.description,
                "Location": user.location,
            }
            temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data=temp_dict, index=[1])
            df_followers = pd.concat([df_followers, temp_df])

        print(len(page))

    df_followers.to_csv("raw_followers.csv", index=False)

except:
    print("Wait for new API Limit!")
    df_followers = pd.read_csv("raw_followers.csv")

return df_followers
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `wait_on_rate_limit` argument to True when you initialize `API` (see [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API)).

On a side note, you don't need the `cnt_pages` argument for `pages` (default is `inf`), and you would go much faster by using the methods of the Twitter API V2.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
But how do i get the user description and location with the client. method (Twitter API V2)? I don't find any solution.

Comment: @amarokWPcom Look like this is a different question, but the fields have the same name in the V2 `User` objects (see the documentation [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/user)). Just don't forget to add `user_fields=['location', 'description']` argument in your get_users_followers(). And please consider marking this answer as the validated answer for your question.